# Data insertion failed in SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am trying to create a person object and want to save that in SQLiteDatabase, but ultimately the data insertion fails. Below are the insertion method and its call. Can you guys tell me, what problem is happening here? Also, I am facing problem to save an image and retrieve it. I have commented out the code to save the image because it was stopping the application.

```
//Insert
long insertPerson(Person person) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //values.put(ID_FIELD, person.getId());
    values.put(NAME_FIELD, person.getName());
    values.put(DOB_FIELD, person.getDateOfBirth());
    values.put(MOBILE_FIELD, person.getMobile());
    values.put(AGE_FIELD, person.getAge());
    values.put(NEXT_BIRTHDAY_FIELD, person.getNext_birthday());
    //values.put(IMAGE_FIELD, person.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream));

    long inserted = db.insert(PERSON_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();

    return inserted;
}
```

Save method

```
//Save data
public void saveData() {
    int id = 0;
    String name, date_of_birth, mobile, age, next_birthday;
    Bitmap profilePicture;

    //Get data from user
    date_of_birth = tv_DoB.getText().toString();
    name = et_name.getText().toString();
    mobile = et_mobile.getText().toString();
    profilePicture = iv_profile_image.getDrawingCache();

    age = final_year + "years old";
    next_birthday = remaining_months + "months" + remaining_days + "days";

    Person person = new Person(id, name, date_of_birth, mobile, age, next_birthday);

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), person.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext(), "person_database", null, 1);

    long inserted = databaseHelper.insertPerson(person);
    if (inserted >= 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data inserted successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data insertion failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ultimately the data insertion fails"?  Do you receive an error?  Does something else happen, or does something not happen that should be happening?

Comment: When I run the program the Toast message is shown

Comment: Do you see any stack traces in the logcat?  Are you sure that the database table exists, that the name of the table in the database is the same as the value in the PERSON_TABLE variable, and that the variables you use for column names all have the correct values according to the database structure?  Are any of the values you are inserting null, but the corresponding database column does not allow null?

Comment: databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext(), "person_database", null, 1); Here should the "person_database" be same as the value of PERSON_TABLE?

Comment: Also if "person_database" be unfortunately be same as the value of DATABASE_NAME will that cause any problem? My program is working fine now after uninstalling and reinstalling the app as Nabin Bhandari said, still if you tell me the answer of these question that will be very helpful.   Also if you give me any suggestion to save and retrieving image in SQLiteDatabase that will be very helpful. Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the following:

- Make sure the database name and schema is correct.
- Uninstall/Clear data of your app from the device and install the app again.

**Reason to uninstall:**

While you are coding, you might have changed the schema of the database. But unfortunately, if the version code of the app is same, upon reinstalling the app with a different schema where old schema already exists, the schema will not be updated. So clearing app data would be the easiest way to allow new schema to be updated.

Comment: Thank you @Nabin Bhandari. After uninstalling and reinstalling the data is being inserted. Can you please tell me what was causing problem? Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: If you give me any suggestion to save and retrieving image in SQLiteDatabase that will be very helpful.

Comment: Please search that in Google.

Comment: I have searched for that, till now I am not successful though. Anyway I shall learn that. Thanks for your support.